# memcache.so, wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0 in MAMP

Tags: mac-osx, mamp

I install memcache from pecl and I got memcache.so. After that I add in php.ini but I got a error.

> [12-Aug-2010 13:02:24] PHP Warning: 
>   PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library
>   '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so,
>   9): no suitable image found.  Did
>   find:
>         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture in
>   Unknown on line 0

I tried

> $file
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

I got

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so:
>   Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64

I'm using Mac OS x 10.6.4 64bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's probbaly because php is not build in 64 bit, so you are trying to load a 64 bit module to a 32 bit application and of course it won't work.
You can check this by running `file` on php binary (or php module if used as module)

Comment: Oh!!! yes. I got result like this. So, how to build i386 edition for memcache ?


php: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
php (for architecture ppc): Mach-O executable ppc
php (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

Comment: I got it. I compile like this.

phpsize

CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common  -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os' ./configure --disable-dependancy-tracking --disable-shared -enable-static

Answer (score 1):

The main answer helped a lot for figuring out that I had compiled wrong, but to compile the module correctly I found this worked for me:

```
$ cd your-php-module
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/phpize
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386" --with-php-config="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php-config"
$ make
$ make install
```